# Bounded and continuous function integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an bounded ($(\exists M>0)(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) |f(x)| \leq M$) and continuous function $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall y \in \mathbb{R})|x-y|<\delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ and nonconstant. Does $f$ have to be integrable?

If there is counterexample, please tell me. If there is some theorem that says so, give me a link.

Comment: It is necessarily *locally* integrable, but not necessarily integrable

Comment: if that helps, since you excluded constant functions, take $f:=\sin$ or $f:=\left|\sin\right|$.

Comment: @Clayton, my bad.  Corrected.

Comment: Here is a nonintegrable (on $\mathbb{R}$) function that satisfies your conditions: $f(x)= 10 + \sin(x)$.

Comment: Another nontrivial example is $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: To be locally integrable, continuity would suffice (not that it is necessary, but the point is that boundedness is superfluous for that result). To be integrable, a necessary but insufficient condition would be that $\liminf\limits_{x\to\infty}|f(x)|=0$.